# What do I do after powering up the trams?

Tags: max-payne-3

I am playing Max Payne 3 on my laptop.  It took me three days to complete the game, but I'm stuck at last part, and can't figure out what to do next.  I've already powered the trams to get them working, and killed the UFE's that reached to me through those same trams.

What am I supposed to do next?

Answer (score 1):

After the train stops, just get off it, which should transition you into a cut scene leading to the penultimate shootout in the aeroplane hanger.

If that explanation doesn't do it for you, take a look at this walkthrough of the final chapter - the train stops at `26:45` in the video: